Elasticsearch FunctionScore doesn't change score for KNN query hits
I added FunctionScore with the FieldValueFactor function to my KNN query, but the search hits scores don't get influenced by the numeric value in the fieldValueFactor.field. I can see the scale of the scores changing when I increase fieldValueFactor.factor or FunctionScore.weight.
The same happens with other than FieldValueFactor functions of FunctionScore.
Either, I am doing this wrong, or ES doesn't support FunctionScore with the KNN query. My ES server is v8.15.4
Here is the relevant excerpt from the ES query I am sending:
  "bool":{
    "must":{
      "function_score":{
        "query":{
          "knn":{
            "field":"vector",
            "query_vector":[....],
            "filter":[
            . . . .
            ]
          }
       },
       "functions":[{
         "field_value_factor":{
         "field":"TwitterScore",
         "factor":1.2,
         "missing":1
       }]
. . . . . . .```


Using _explain
Have you tried using the _explain api ? it gives you a break down of how the score was computed.
Demo
GET <some index>/_explain/<_id of a matching doc>
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "knn": {
                "field": "ml.inference.body_content.predicted_value",
                "query_vector_builder": {
                  "text_embedding": {
                    "model_id": ".multilingual-e5-small_linux-x86_64",
                    "model_text": " .... "
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "TwitterScore",
                  "factor": 1.2,
                  "missing": 2.5
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Should give you something along those lines:
{
  "_index": "<some index>",
  "_id": "<_id doc>",
  "matched": true,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 2.8142061,
    "description": "function score, product of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 0.93806875,
        "description": "within top 15",
        "details": []
      },
      {
        "value": 3,
        "description": "min of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 3,
            "description": "field value function: none(doc['TwitterScore'].value?:2.5 * factor=1.2)",
            "details": []
          },
          {
            "value": 3.4028235e+38,
            "description": "maxBoost",
            "details": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

In my case you can see that the Knn search gave it a score of 0.93806875.
And the field_value_factor a value of 3 (2.5*1.2)
Giving me an end result of 2.8142061

Yes, I used _explain, but it only showed application of the "missing" value.

Many thanks to @Paulo, his response confirming the function score functionality working as it should, encouraged me to thoroughly examine everything in my query, and I found that one of the chars in the field_value_factor field name was not ascii, hence elasticserach was not finding that field and applying the "field missing" default.

Hi @Sasha, happy that I was of help. Please to not post response with thank you notes. You may give an upvote or leave a comment. You risk to be down voted
